# How to set Different Auto logout time for each user in Laravel when user is ideal

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I have a time in mins for each one user in his profile, the user should automatically be logged out after that time.

Example:

User 1: Auto logout time => 60 Mins

User 2: Auto logout time => 120 Mins

User 3: Auto logout time => 150 Mins

So after login, user 1 should log out after 60 mins of login, user 2 after 120 mins and user 3 after 150 mins. Does anyone have any idea that how to achieve this?

I am thinking to change the session lifetime from the session.php file for every login request, but don't know it will work or Not.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can save Logout time for each user when they login in DB and doing AJAX call after some interval. On each AJAX call you can check logout time with current time and if time exceeds logout user.

Comment: you didn't get my qestion man, I need to check the ideal time and after that i need to logout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can use `setInterval` javascript function

```
    var timeoutSeconds = <?php echo Session::get('timeoutSeconds'); ?>
    var _idleSecondsCounter = 0;

    window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, timeoutSeconds);

    function CheckIdleTime() {
        _idleSecondsCounter++;
        var oPanel = document.getElementById("SecondsUntilExpire");
        if (oPanel)
            oPanel.innerHTML = (IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter) + "";
        if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
            document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();
        }
    }
```

In login controller you can set session like this

```
 $userCount = 1;

 $timeOutSeconds = 60 * $userCount;

 Session::put('timeoutSeconds', $timeOutSeconds);
```

**For Server Side**

Create a Background Job in Laravel and do a delayed dispatch after login method.

[Delayed Job Dispatch](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#delayed-dispatching)

Comment: A client side solution isn't very secure for this.

Comment: Yes I agree with @RoryMcCrossan. If you need this in server side then I think need to add a scheduler to check whether the current user having valid session or not. If not logout

Comment: Yes @RoryMcCrossan, I agree with you it's not secure, Isn't there another way to do this?

Comment: I don't know enough about PHP/Laravel to give you a solution, but that is definitely where you need to be looking

Comment: Ok. Thanks, Appreciate your help.

Comment: @AmolRokade You can create  a background job and do a delayed dispatch after login https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#delayed-dispatching

Comment: Ok. I will check it. Thanks for your help.